# NHibernate Criteria Query vs. LINQ to NHibernate

Tags: performance, linq-to-nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I understand that there are queries you can't express in LINQ to NHibernate that you can using NHibernate Criteria. But, as far performance, is it safe to assume that using NHibernate Criteria is generally better than LINQ to NHibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though NHibernate Criteria is better in terms of performance, NHibernate Linq provides compile time checking. I rarely have seen any project having issues using any of the 2 since the performance gains are miniscule.

In my case I usually use Linq except in cases where I cannot express them and then I have to use ICriteria.  The benefit of compile time checking outweighs the minor performance gains.

Comment: Way to resurrect this question! :)